# Debugging ES6 mdules in browser

Tags: angularjs, babeljs, es6-modules

I have a large angular 1.6 application. Most of it is written in ES5 syntax and some small parts are sort of ES6. I'm saying sort of ES6 because we don't actually use modules/import/export. The reason for that is although we do use gulp to bundle all source code when deploying, we don't want to do that on dev, because it involves running gulp every small code change, and running it takes time, plus the fact that its much nicer to debug the original file per class structure rather then the bundled code (even when not uglified).

Is there a way, to debug angular 1.6 in ES6 syntax without bundling? Can Babel somehow help me keep the original files structure, for development purposes only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel is basically a transpiler, so its job is only to make sure to output es5 code. It will NOT help u organize folder structure.

Bundling it with webpack helps u maintain a sane folder structure. u can have a configuration object which specifies your entry-point,(called "entry"), output-file, loaders, inline : true, so it automagically refreshes the browser for you for any small change. webpack also comes with a dev-server.

Below is what i use in my webpack.config.js.
It helps me maintain a local sandbox for my es6 escapades.

```
module.exports = {
  entry : ['./app/index.js'], //entrypoint
  output: {
    path: 'D:\\js\\es6\\build',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [ //specify objects for each loader
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader' ,
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude:  /node_modules/, //we dont want to transpile the .js on node_modules
        }
      ]
  },
  devServer: {
      port: 3000,
      contentBase: './build',
      inline: true, //allows us to run automatic live code update
  }
}
```

Comment: but as I can see, it will all be in bundle.js isn't it? I won't be able to see my original files in debugging, won't I?

Comment: u can see ur original files when u debug on chrome, under >webpack . For eg. I use it with ang2 project and I can see my .ts (typescript) files there. (u may have to refresh the page once more).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Also, I see that it runs on port 3000. Will that effect me running .Net application on port 80 or is it just the webpack dev server? Do you know any good sample app that I use as a reference for webpack and angular?

Comment: It shouldnt impact ur server-side application on port 80. u can alternatively try live-server (which can make any folder, yes any-folder, into a web DocumentRoot) instead of webpack-dev-server . A good project in my opinion using both of these can be found https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter  (see package.json). Unfortunately, the angular-seed project should have more forks to include webpack, etc. But it does not have it. try the angular starter project, it should give u some point of reference